# Use an array of objects in another class

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new at Java and I'm trying to create an array of objects without using the collection ArrayList. What I want to do is to **create an array of objects for constructor** "Passenger" class in main class and **instantiate it in class SubwayManager** in method "showPassenger" where I can return a specific Passenger with a given name passed by parameter but I don't have any idea how I can do this. Would really appreciate any help.

Here's my Passenger class:

```
public class Passenger {

    private String name;
    private String nif;
    private String birthDate;
    private boolean student;
   
 
    public Passenger(String name, String nif, String birthDate) {

        this.name = name;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.student = false;
        
    }
```

Here's the **main class** where I created the array of Passengers objects:

```
public class IPOO_P2 {
   
 private static Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[10];
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
      
        SubwayManager man1 = new SubwayManager();
       
       for(int i=0; i<passengers.length; i++){
            passengers[0] = new Passenger("nomee", "298282928", "29-12-2022");
            passengers[1] = new Passenger("nomee2", "2982829281", "29-12-2021");
            passengers[2] = man1.createPassenger("name", "nif", "birthdate");
        }
   
        man1.showPassenger("nomee");
    } 
}
```

And here's the class SubwayManager **where I want to use the array of Passengers**:

```
public class SubwayManager {

    private DataBase db;
    private Menu menu;
    private Passenger[] passengers;

    public SubwayManager() {
        this.db = new DataBase();
        this.menu = new Menu(this);
        passengers = new Passenger[10];
    }

//the method where I want to instantiate and use the array of Passengers
   public void showPassenger(String name) {

        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
            if (passengers[i].getNif().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println(passengers[i].toString());
            }else{System.out.println("There isn't any passenger with that name");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameterized subway manager constructor. Put your passenger array in it. Then your show passenger method should work.